# Unable to get complete data using mysql 3 joins query

Tags: mysql, sql

i have 1500 records in domains table but by using this query only get 1215 records. How to modify this query to give desired outcome and better performance

```
SELECT 
  d.id, d.domain_name, d.action, d.comment, d.agent_email, 
  d.assigned_date, d.added_date, dd.registered_on, dd.expiry_date,
  dd.updated_date, dd.acquire_price, dd.acquire_date, dd.email,
  dd.effective_price, dd.registrar, dd.status, dd.servers, 
  count(l.lead_domain), d.domainer_email, d.current_status, 
  d.undeveloped, d.sedo, d.afternic, d.flippa, d.uniregistry, 
  d.go_daddy, d.domr, d.minimum_offer, d.buy_it_now_price, 
  d.way_to_find_leads, dd.tlds_taken 
FROM domains d 
right join domains_data dd on d.domain_name=dd.domain_name 
left outer join lead_domains l on d.domain_name=l.domain_name 
  and d.domainer_email=l.domainer_email 
group by d.domain_name 
having d.action='all' and d.domainer_email='abc@gmail.com' 
order by d.added_date desc;
```

Comment: provide sample data and your expected output in table format

Comment: RIGHT JOIN and LEFT JOIN combined... That's just too much. Most people find `main table left join optional data` much easier to understand than `optional data right join main table`. (BTW, thanks to the HAVING clause your RIGHT JOIN returns inner join result anyway.)

Comment: That GROUP BY is invalid and won't run on newer MySQL versions, unless in compatibility mode. (You typically GROUP BY the same columns as you SELECT, except those who are arguments to set functions.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Harshal As per my understanding, I don't think that query you have provided will work as GROUP BY rules are not followed properly.

```
SELECT  d.id,
        d.domain_name,
        d.action,
        d.comment,
        d.agent_email,
        d.assigned_date,
        d.added_date,
        dd.registered_on,
        dd.expiry_date,
        dd.updated_date,
        dd.acquire_price,
        dd.acquire_date,
        dd.email,
        dd.effective_price,
        dd.registrar,
        dd.status,
        dd.servers,
        (SELECT COUNT(lead_domain) FROM lead_domains WHERE domain_name = d.domain_name AND domainer_email = d.domainer_email) AS lead_domain,
        d.domainer_email,
        d.current_status,
        d.undeveloped,
        d.sedo,
        d.afternic,
        d.flippa,
        d.uniregistry,
        d.go_daddy,
        d.domr,
        d.minimum_offer,
        d.buy_it_now_price,
        d.way_to_find_leads,
        dd.tlds_taken
FROM domains d
LEFT JOIN domains_data dd 
       ON d.domain_name = dd.domain_name
WHERE d.action = 'all'
      AND d.domainer_email = 'abc@gmail.com'
ORDER BY
    d.added_date DESC;
```

And as you have not provided any expected results, I am just guessing that my solution will work.

Comment: Thank It works for me and time to get data is also reduced

Answer (score 1):

Your results depend on the `domains_data` table.

Since you are right joining `domains` to `domains_data`, the entries that are in `domains_data` are taken. If you want the entries of `domains` to be considered, use a left join like below.

```
SELECT d.id, d.domain_name, d.action, d.comment, d.agent_email, d.assigned_date, d.added_date, dd.registered_on, dd.expiry_date, dd.updated_date, dd.acquire_price, dd.acquire_date, dd.email, dd.effective_price, dd.registrar, dd.status, dd.servers, COUNT(l.lead_domain), d.domainer_email, d.current_status, d.undeveloped, d.sedo, d.afternic, d.flippa, d.uniregistry, d.go_daddy, d.domr, d.minimum_offer, d.buy_it_now_price, d.way_to_find_leads, dd.tlds_taken
FROM domains d
LEFT JOIN domains_data dd ON d.domain_name=dd.domain_name
LEFT OUTER JOIN lead_domains l ON d.domain_name=l.domain_name AND d.domainer_email=l.domainer_email
GROUP BY d.domain_name
HAVING d.action='all' AND d.domainer_email='abc@gmail.com'
ORDER BY d.added_date DESC;
```

If you are still not able to get the desired results, check the `having` conditions.

Comment: need to change in having clause but there only 2 fieds by which i have to filter the data

Comment: there is a `If` in front of my sentence

Answer (score 0):

Here's my suggestion, filter first before joining other tables.

```
SELECT d.id
    ,d.domain_name
    ,d.action
    ,d.comment
    ,d.agent_email
    ,d.assigned_date
    ,d.added_date
    ,dd.registered_on
    ,dd.expiry_date
    ,dd.updated_date
    ,dd.acquire_price
    ,dd.acquire_date
    ,dd.email
    ,dd.effective_price
    ,dd.registrar
    ,dd.status
    ,dd.servers
    ,t1.cnt
    ,d.domainer_email
    ,d.current_status
    ,d.undeveloped
    ,d.sedo
    ,d.afternic
    ,d.flippa
    ,d.uniregistry
    ,d.go_daddy
    ,d.domr
    ,d.minimum_offer
    ,d.buy_it_now_price
    ,d.way_to_find_leads
    ,dd.tlds_taken 
FROM domains d 
inner join
    (select domain_name, count(1) as cnt 
        from domain
        where
            action='all' and domainer_email='abc@gmail.com'
        group by domain_name
     ) as t1 on t1.domain_name = d.domain_name
right join domains_data dd on d.domain_name=dd.domain_name 
left outer join lead_domains l on d.domain_name=l.domain_name and d.domainer_email=l.domainer_email 
order by d.added_date desc;
```